# Download force file adds underscore "_" to downloaded filename

Tags: php, file-upload

this is my script for file downloading

The problem is that when downloading a file lets say file name is music, the file name is changed to

> _var_www_myporject_module_Application_musicdir_music

which i donot desire

This is the snippet to my code

```
public function downloadAction() {
    $filename = $this->params()->fromQuery('filename');
    $file = "/var/www/myproject/module/Application/musicDir/$filename";

    if ($file) {
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Download");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename = $file");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        readfile($file);
        exit;
    } else {
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: File names cannot contain slashes in most file systems. Are you by chance trying to suggest a "Save as" directory? You cannot.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename = $file");
```

to :

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename = $filename");
```

So that it will show only file name, not directory names.